# Android visual effect hides and shows items

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I'm trying to reproduce this done in my activity, when I move the list down it hides some item animatedly.

Note that the search field does not add up in this example.

Anyone know how I can get this done shown in the GIF below?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM5JT.gif)

**Thanks for the help solution was put `android: nestedScrollingEnabled = "true"` in ListView**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview1"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<alexandreapp.com.br.pensouchegoucliente.CustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?colorAccent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="My Custom View"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you can use the Coordinator layout

eg.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    prepareData();
    setUpRecyclerView();
}

private void prepareData() {
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        mList.add(String.valueOf(random.nextInt(100)));
}

private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager
        .VERTICAL, false));
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(mList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

}
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Basically the lines which will make your view hide and show are:

`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` which should be added in the view that you want to hide/show

and

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your list or your scrolling view

in the example above those lines are in the Toolbar and RecyclerView, so when you scroll the recyclerview the toolbar should hide

Comment: I tested your example but did not achieve the.

Comment: I updated my question, but when I move the listview nothing happens.

Comment: yes, I'm rolling the list, so at the moment it only works when I try to roll the toolbar up it hides the blue part before the EditText.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It's working fine here, so you can just do the same